# How to make dynamically Tree in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, tree, bulletedlist

I have a table called "Tabel_Items" in database with these fields: `id`, `parent`, and `child`:

[image]

I want to generate html tags such as these:

```
<ul>
    <li>parent1
        <ul>
            <li>child1</li>
            <li>child2
                <ul>
                    <li>child21</li>
                    <li>child22</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>parent2
        <ul>
            <li>child3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I get my items with a LINQ query and pass them to view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var items = from i in db.Table_Items
                select i;

    return View(items);
}
```

How can I loop through the "items" in view and make a Tree list out of them?

---

I want a lambda expression to select those rows that have "parentId==null" at first. I test a code like this, but has an error:

```
@foreach (var i in Model)
{
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => i.ItemName.Where(i.ParentId==null));
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Part of the problem is your data design. Your table should have these fields: Id, ItemName, ParentId. And, you should create a one-to-many relationship using Id as primary key and ParentId as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.Thank for me:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var x in Model.Where(f => f.ParentId == null))
{
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(f => x.ItemName)
        <ul>
            @foreach (var y in Model.Where(c => c.ParentId == x.Id))
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(c => y.ItemName)
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var z in Model.Where(c => c.ParentId == y.Id))
                        {
                            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(c => z.ItemName)</li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```